# 2d Index on MongoDB with nested object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, geospatial, mean-stack

I have a **mongoDB Schema** like this:

```
var PlumberSchema = new Schema({
        firstname: {
            type: String
        },
        ...
        office: {
            address:{ type:String },
            location: { type:[Number], index: '2d'}
        }
        ...
 }
```

Where that *index:'2d'* is the position where I need to create a 2D Index for geospatial search.

In order to do that I have read the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/build-a-2d-index/ and there is an example that for convenience I report:

```
db.<collection>.createIndex( {<location field> : "<index type>"}
```

that could help me if my Schema was:

```
var PlumberSchema = new Schema({
        firstname: {
            type: String
        },
        ...
        address:{ type:String },
        location: { type:[Number], index: '2d'}
        ...
 }
```

To create an Index in that case I would write:

```
db.<collection>.createIndex( {location:"2d"})
```

But as you can see I have a *nested object*. How I could manage it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.<collection>.createIndex( {"office.location":"2d"})
```

Comment: Tried. And it does not work.
Then I try to execute the query with: 

db.<collection>.find({ office: { location: { $near: [11.255814, 43.769560], $maxDistance: 0.10 } } }), but no results are obtained.

Comment: This query is for `2dsphere` indexes (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/) and `maxDistance` is in meters, so you're querying for 10 centimetres, not sure if should return anything.